# Pig Store Output to ElasesticSearch getting ERROR

Tags: hadoop, curl, elasticsearch, apache-pig

Trying to store pig expected output into elastic-search index.

But getting String index out of range: -1 exception

**Expected-output:-**

```
(google_1473682742_265278445560,{(Thu Apr 12 17:38:47 +0000 2012,190494185374220289,190494185374220289,google اااااح الاجواء بتاعت سكس حااااارر منو الفحل اللي يبي اسوي له  فولو يسوي رتويت,<a href="http://blackberry.com/twitter" rel="nofollow">Twitter for BlackBerry®</a>,[hashtags#[],user_mentions#[],urls#[]],false,,0,false,),(Thu Apr 12 17:38:47 +0000 2012,190494185382608899,190494185382608899,kpit 味も素っ気もない人間とは…。,<a href="http://tapbots.com/tweetbot" rel="nofollow">Tweetbot for iOS</a>,[hashtags#[],user_mentions#[],urls#[]],false,,0,false,)})
```

**describe output;-**

```
output: {pattern: chararray,tweets: {(lowertweets::created_at: chararray,lowertweets::id: chararray,lowertweets::id_str: chararray,lowertweets::text: chararray,lowertweets::source: chararray,lowertweets::entities: map[chararray],lowertweets::favorited: boolean,lowertweets::favorite_count: long,lowertweets::retweet_count: long,lowertweets::retweeted: boolean,lowertweets::place: map[chararray])}}
```

**script:-**

```
STORE A INTO 'google_1473673952_265276863360/tweets' USING org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.EsStorage('es.nodes = ip:9200','es.mapping.pig.tuple.use.field.names = true');
```

**Curl Script:-**

```
curl -XPUT 'http://hostname:9200/google_1473673952_265276863360/_mapping/tweets' -d ' {     "tweets" :{     "properties" : {            "pattern" : " {"type" : "string", "store" : true},  "created_at" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"id" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true }, "id_str" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"text" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"source" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"entities" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"favorited" : {"type" : "boolean", "store" : true },"favorite_count" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"retweet_count" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"retweeted" : {"type" : "boolean", "store" : true },"place" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true } }}}'
```

**Error:-**

java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: **String index out of range: -1** at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529) Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:479) at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:442)

I tried by changing the datatypes in curl but it didn't worked me

Any help

Answer (score 0):

your mapping has an error, an extra ".

try using this

```
{  "properties" : { "pattern" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true},  "created_at" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"id" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true }, "id_str" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"text" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"source" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"entities" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"favorited" : {"type" : "boolean", "store" : true },"favorite_count" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"retweet_count" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true },"retweeted" : {"type" : "boolean", "store" : true },"place" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true } }}
```

Comment: Ok..I corrected it and tried it again.But still getting the same issue.java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529) Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 at